# VBA Open several HTML files in Spreadsheets only in the Workbook currently open

Tags: html, vba, excel, excel-2010

I am downloading HTML files using VBA and Python. These files are on a file directory like `C:\files`. Every download gives me about 7 - 12 HTML files.

What I want is a way to open each HTML file **on one workbook the one which i currently work with.**

By using the `Open` function of `VBA` for every `HTML` file i get a new workbook which creates congestion and mess.

Is there a way to have a command inside the loop which opens the HTML file on new tab **and inside** the current workbook?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of two options: move the sheet from the new workbook into the current one each time; or look at using Querytables.

Moving the sheet is straightforward:

```
Dim wb As Workbook
For Each varFilePath In colFilePaths           'whatever your loop logic is...
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(varFilePath)
        wb.Worksheets(1).Copy Before:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
        wb.Close False
Next varFilePath
```

The other option, Querytables, is designed to extract data from HTML rather than just create a worksheet that looks close to how the HTML will render in a browser.  Generally the results won't look the same as the webpage, but you do get more control.  This may or may not be helpful depending on what you are going to do with the data afterwards.  See the VBA documentation for `QueryTables` for more info, but the basic steps are to create a new `QueryTable` pointing at your file and the destination cell, set options, and then call its `Refresh` method to populate cells:

```
'inside your loop...
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
Set qt = ws.QueryTables.Add("URL;file:///" & varFilePath, ws.Range("A1"))
'set various options here...
qt.WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingAll
qt.WebSelectionType = xlEntirePage
'Get the data
qt.Refresh
```

Comment: Thanks for the great answer i didn't knew about Querytables!!!! However there is one thing i would like to ask. In the first solution where you move the sheet...Is there any way to copy the tab to the active workbook without opening the wb which is the source and the data is copied from? Somehow copy a tab from a source workbook without opening it...

Comment: I don't _think_ so.  If it's an Excel file then really you need to open it to work with it from VBA.  For other file types (e.g. HTML or XML) you can read from them direct - but that's effectively what the Querytables option above is doing.

Comment: Okay i have the HTML files downloaded in my directory... Instead of opening them with Excel i can use Querytables to get what i want and not have to open the whole HTML with Excel and copy the whole tab with Excel. Is this right?